# How to add delete button on each record in pageBlock table - VF

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension, pageblocktable, extension

I have an extension that allows users to input information and I am trying to add delete functionality to each record in `apex:pageBlockTable`. How can I edit my extension code to add this?

What I've tried:

```
    public with sharing class ecrjcClass{
    
    public class participantWrapper{
        public participant__c par {get;set;}
        public Boolean checked {get;set;}
        
        public participantWrapper(participant__c par, Boolean checked){
            this.par = par;
            this.checked = checked;
        }
    }
    
    public Participant__c record {get;set;}
    public List<Participant__c> allrecords {get;set;}
    public Referral__c ref {get;set;}
    public Boolean checked {get;set;}


    public ecrjcClass(){
        record = new Participant__c();
        allrecords = new List<Participant__c>();
        ref = new Referral__c();
    }   

    //Add a record row
    public pageReference Add_Row(){

        Participant__c anotherRecord = new Participant__c();   
        anotherRecord.Name = record.Name;
        anotherRecord.Last_Name__c = record.Last_Name__c;
        anotherRecord.Age__c = record.Age__c;
        anotherRecord.Victim_Offender__c = record.Victim_Offender__c;
        anotherRecord.Phone__c = record.Phone__c;
        
        insert ref;
        
        anotherRecord.Referral__c = ref.Id;
        //Issue: Need to insert ref first
        allrecords.add(new participantWrapper(anotherRecord, false));
        return null;        
        
    }
    
    //Save and insert records in list
    public pageReference save(){
        
        insert allrecords;
        return null;
            
    }
    
    //Delete button on each record on apex table
public void deleteChecked(){
    List<participantWrapper> wrappers = new List<participantWrapper>();        
    List<Participant__c> dltCase = new List<Participant__c>();
    for(participantWrapper cc: allrecords) {
        if(cc.checked) {
            dltCase.add(cc.par);
        } else {
            wrappers.add(cc);
        }
    }
    delete dltCase;
    allrecords = wrappers;
    }
}
```

VF page

```
    <apex:page controller="ecrjcClass" lightningStyleSheets="true">

<!-- Logo and header -->
<br/>
<br/>
<div style="text-align: center">
    <apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.ecrjcLogo)}" height="300" width="300"> 
    </apex:image>            
<br/>
<br/>

<h1>Referral Form</h1>
</div>

<!--Form begins-->
<!--General info-->

<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="General information" columns="2">
        <apex:inputField value="{!Ref.Date__c}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Ref.Referral_Date__c}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Ref.Referring_Agency__c}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Ref.Mailing_Street__c}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Ref.Mailing_City__c}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Ref.Mailing_Country__c}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Ref.Mailing_State_Province__c}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Ref.Mailing_ZIP_Postal__c}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    
    <!--Referrer Information-->
    <apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Referrer Information">
        <apex:inputField value="{!Ref.Referrer_Name__c}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Ref.Referrer_Phone__c}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Ref.Referrer_Email__c}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    
    <apex:pageBlock >
    <!--Participant info-->
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Partipicant Information">
        <apex:inputField value="{!record.Name}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!record.Last_Name__c}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!record.Age__c}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!record.Phone__c}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!record.Victim_Offender__c}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>     
    <!--Add participant to record list-->    
        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
        <apex:commandButton action="{!Add_Row}" value="Add Participant"/>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>   
    
            <apex:pageBlock title="Added Participants">
        <apex:pageBlockTable id="Participants" value="{!allrecords}" var="Participant">
            <apex:column>
                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!Participant.checked}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="First Name" value="{!Participant.par.Name}"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="Last Name" value="{!Participant.par.Last_Name__c}"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="Age" value="{!Participant.par.Age__c}"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="Phone" value="{!Participant.par.Phone__c}"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="Victim/Offender" value="{!Participant.par.Victim_Offender__c}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
            <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Submit"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Thank you.

Edit: Errors:

- Invalid field checked for SObject Participant__c
- Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void add(ecrjcClass.participantWrapper) from the type List<Participant__c>
- Invalid loop variable type expected Participant__c was ecrjcClass.participantWrapper
- Illegal assignment from List<ecrjcClass.participantWrapper> to List<Participant__c>

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the wrapper to the list:

```
allrecords.add(new caseWrapper(record, false));
```

Your page block needs to reference the case, and allow for the checkbox:

```
        <apex:column>
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!Participant.checked}" />
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="First Name" value="{!Participant.cas.Participant_First_Name__c}"/>
        <apex:column headerValue="Last Name" value="{!Participant.cas.Participant_Last_Name__c}"/>
        <apex:column headerValue="Age" value="{!Participant.cas.Participant_Age__c}"/> 
        <apex:column headerValue="Phone" value="{!Participant.cas.Participant_Phone__c}"/>
        <apex:column headerValue="Victim/Offender" value="{!Participant.cas.Participant_is_victim_or_offender__c}"/>
```

Finally, you'll want to remove the items after deletion:

```
//Delete button on each record on apex table
public void deleteChecked(){
    List<casewrapper> wrappers = new List<caseWrapper>();        
    List<Case> dltCase = new List<case>();
    for(caseWrapper cc: allrecords) {
        if(cc.checked) {
            dltCase.add(cc.cas);
        } else {
            wrappers.add(cc);
        }
    }
    delete dltCase;
    allrecords = wrappers;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am getting quite a few errors using this method. Please see updated code